# this used inside class' method/function vs this used inside anonymous function?

Tags: actionscript

Why "this" behaves differently when used inside a class function/method  as compared to when it is used inside an anonymous function.

For example

```
public MyClass 
{

     function myfun()
     {
        output(this) // << will show the instance of this class but not myfun() function

        abc = function ()
        {

            output ( this ) // << will show abc function 
        }

        abc()
     }

}
```

So, why "this" outputs the instance of MyClass but doesnot output myfun() . What makes it different from anonymous functions ?

Comment: What language did you test this in? I'm not sure which languages even support that kind of anonymous function.

Comment: Ecmascript decendents like javascript and actionscript have the concept of anonymous functions

Comment: @VishwasGagrani but ECMAScript/JavaScript doesn't have classes, so what language is this here? I could explain this in JavaScript if the top level there was `function bla() {` instead of `public MyClass {`, but as it is I have no idea what this code refers to precisely.

Comment: @Jimmy: Actionscript 3.0 has class and anonymous function both.

Comment: @VishwasGagrani as does C# and many other languages, but this is *not* language-agnostic because the behaviour you're speaking of is not common among languages. "this" changes based on scope depth in JavaScript but not in any languages that have classes I'm aware of (other than apparently ActionScript?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the specific will vary between languages, the general idea behind an anonymous inline method such as that is that the compiler will create a new class (possibly given some random name, just for it's own use), inside that class will be a method (again, probably given some auto-generated name for it's own use) and that method will do the work of the anonymous method.  Then in the original call site of the anonymous method it creates an instance of this compiler generated class and calls the appropriate method within that class.

As such, the definition of that anonymous method is going to actually be called from within another type, not from within the type that declared the anonymous method.